# if $K\subset G$ there is an $\epsilon>0$ such tht $K_\epsilon\subset G$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(M, d)$ be a metric space and $K$ a compact set and $G$ an open set such that $K\subset G$ .

Is it true that there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that $K\subset K_\epsilon \subset G$?

Notation: $K_\epsilon = \{x\in M: d(x,K)\leq \epsilon\}$ and $d(x,K)=\inf \{d(x,k):k\in K\}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since $G$ is open, for every $x\in K$ there exists $\epsilon_x$ with $B(x,\epsilon_x)\subset G$. Now $$K\subset\bigcup_{x\in K}B(x,\epsilon_x/2).$$

Comment: Oh yes, Thanks.

Comment: Make certain to see the edit. Not every point of $B(x,\epsilon_x)$ is at any given distance from thhe complement of $G$, but $y\in B(x,\epsilon_x/2)$ implies $B(y,\epsilon_x/2)\subset G$.

Comment: Just to be sure: There is a subcover like $K\subset \cup_{i=1}^n B(x_i, \epsilon_{x_i}/2)$ Now let $\epsilon=\min \{\epsilon_{x_i}/2\}$ then $K_\epsilon\subset G$ since for each $x\in K_\epsilon$ we have $d(x,K)\leq \epsilon$ now since $K$ is compact there is a $x_0\in K$ such that $d(x,K)=d(x,x_0)$ and since $x_0\in B(x_i,\epsilon_{x_i}/2)$ we have $d(x, x_i)\leq d(x,x_0)+d(x_0,x_i)<\epsilon +\epsilon_{x_i}/2<\epsilon_{x_i}$ so $x\in B(x_i,\epsilon_{x_i})\subset G$

Comment: Yippee!${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true. Suppose it was not true, then for every integer $n>0$, you have $x_n\in K_{1/n}$, $x_n$ is not in $G$. There exists $y_n\in K$ such that $d(x_n,y_n)\leq 1/n$. Since $K$ is compact, you can suppose (up to a subsequence) that $(y_n)$ converges towards $y$, $d(y,x_n)\leq d(x_n,y_n)+d(y_n,x_n)$ implies that $x_n$ converges towards $y$. This implies that there exists $c>0,N$ such that $x_n\in B(y,c)\subset G$ for $n>N$. Contradiction.